# Does anyone know how to download Photoshop csh custom shape for triangle?

Tags: photoshop

I'm using Photoshop CC & my "custom shape tool" does not have triangle shape which I need to use. I have searched everywhere for geometric shapes such as triangle but I haven't found any useful shape. So please if you know how to download one ,please let me know ! Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Polygoon Tool** by setting sides to 3 (equilateral triangle). You can also use **Pen Tool**.

Try search in Google about that.